# Windows server crashs in video transcode during

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using ffmpeg for transcoding of my videos on a HP Blade dedicated server with these details:

**OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 64Bit 

CPU: Intel XEON X5650 

RAM: 16GB 

Hard disk: A sas normal disk**

This command is a sample for creating qualities which has 4K as top level and I use this command for creating lower qualities from that as parallel at the same time.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex 
[0:v]split=4[s0][s1][s2][s3];
[s0]scale=uhd2160[v0];
[s1]scale=hd1080[v1];
[s2]scale=hd720[v2];
[s3]scale=hd480[v3];
[s4]scale=nhd[v4];
[s5]scale=cga[v5]
-map [v0] -map [v1] -map [v2] -map [v3] -map [v4] -map [v5] -map 0:a 
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee -g 48 -threads 0 
"[select='v\:0,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0:hls_time=6]../video/2160p/out.m3u8| 
 [select='v\:1,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0:hls_time=6]../video/1080p/out.m3u8| 
 [select='v\:2,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0:hls_time=6]../video/720p/out.m3u8| 
 [select='v\:3,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/480p/out.m3u8| 
 [select='v\:3,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0:hls_time=6]video/360p/out.m3u8| 
 [select='v\:3,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0:hls_time=6]video/200p/out.m3u8"
```

Some times in transcoding time windows goes to reconnecting and count up to 20 and then goes to black screen. I cannot find anythings in windows logs. And finally I restart server from button of that server. What's hapenning? How can I find a clue, about this issue? 
Any one know anything about this issue?

Comment: Is it a single command? If yes then add backslash after every line and use it from a batch file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have enough free disk space on the system disk?

Comment: @harrymc Yes I have

Comment: Ideas: Look in the Event Viewer for information of what happened. Use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to see if you had Windows crashes and to analyze them.

Comment: @harrymc ,Thank you so much for your recommendation, I used BlueScreenView, and it showed hal.dll had problem. last week I updated this dll and no have see any problem up to now.
If I don't see any problem, I'll mark up your recommendation as the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Good. I added this advice as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools to analyze such a problem:

- Look in the Event Viewer for information of what happened.
- Use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)
  to see if you had Windows crashes and for help in analyzing them.

Comment: After about 1 week, the server crashed again

Comment: These are analysis tools. But what have you found? What does BlueScreenView show? Add screenshots if you want us to have a look. Or use another conversion utility.

Comment: It showed that log of last crashed that related to hal.dll. I Update hal.dll, but cashing occured again, After last crash, in BlueScreenView there are not any new crash log.
But it occured again

Comment: You can't update `hal.dll` - it's an essential Windows component that only Windows can update. What was done?

Comment: In some servers,hal.dll was update, and in some of servers os couldn't run

Comment: Although hal.dll on several servers have been successfully upgraded, but after some days, on two server crash occured.
But in in BlueScreenView there is no any logs about last occurence that related to that specific date.

Comment: Some details will help in analyzing the problem.

Comment: 1 - I download hal.dll from https://www.dll-files.com/hal.dll.html.
2 - For example I reboot the server which have been WinServer 2012 r2 as os in cmd with command `shutdown /o /r` for going to command prompt.
3 - In command prompt I run this command `d:Users\Administrator\desktop\>expand hal.dll D:\Windows\System32`
4 - Finally I rebooted the server.

Comment: You should *never* install Windows DLLs from non-Windows sources. Never. There is now an incoherence between the level of `hal.dll` and the rest of Windows, so it is not possible any more to analyze the problem. All I can suggest is to boot from an installation CD and choose Repair to return things to a known state, then run Windows Update as many times as required.

Comment: Thank you. I try as your recommendation and I declare the results,
Thank you